# How I use SMTP mail in Titanium?

Tags: android, iphone, titanium

I want to send mail through the help of SMTP server. currently I am using CreateEmailDailog but in this, when press Send button then mail is sent.
I want to with any press my mail is send in background. I want to use  set recipient, subject and message body default.
any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ready-made SMTP support in Titanium SDK. You need to implement yourself with using TCPSocket operations.

Check http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.0/index.html#!/api/Titanium.Network.Socket.TCP for documentation and example code.

SMTP protocol is easy. There are few commands like; EHLO, MAIL FROM, RCPT TO, AUTH LOGIN, DATA, QUIT. You can find all protocol specification on RFC documentations.